# Is there something in python i can use to represent any positive whole number

Tags: python, list, function, search, numbers

Id like to know if there is something specific in python that simply represents any whole number. Specifically I want to know this so I can use said specific something (symbol or built in function I guess) to use in a search algorithm. This is so i dont have to search for precisely the right numbers just the first set of data with 2 of the right numbers and one whole positive number.

This is the code im using for this:

```
def pheromone():
'''function to measure the level of pheromone (whilst slowly depleting that level) in the grid cells in order to increase or decrease the likelihood an ant will choose that grid cell'''
    grid_list[grid_list.index([ant_position[0],ant_position[1],SOMESYMBOL])]
```

The grid list is a list containing lists. So im searching for the first list out of the grid list to have the two set values im looking for (ant_position[0] and ant_position[1]) and one arbitrary value that could concievably be any whole positive number displayed here as SOMESYMBOL.

Any one got any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're looking for some sort of wildcard. Unfortunately, there is no such thing. However, luckily enough, there might just be a data structure better for you than a list: a dictionary.

Rather than having a list of tuples of X, Y, and related data, I'd recommend having a dictionary mapping from the pair X, Y to whatever data is necessary. Then your code might look like this:

```
def pheromone():
    grid_dict[(ant_position[0], ant_position[1])]
```

It should be similarly simple to add and remove items; to add:

```
grid_dict[(x, y)] = data
```

To remove:

```
del grid_dict[(x, y)]
```

Comment: ok so theres no easy way to do this then? :L oh well and mmm maybe but ive already done what for me is alot of coding using my method of lists so I dont think ill be switching now :/ but ill definetely look into lists next time I have to do something like this :)

Comment: @user2966742: I second the recommendation of switching to dicts - your use case really suits a hashtable much better. You will also see significant improvements in speed when searching (`O(n)` vs `O(1)` average case)

Comment: hmmmm well I think im in too deep to switch now so if you can think of any way to hack it together it would be greatly appreciated :L

Comment: @user2966742: You can use a `for` loop to loop over the list and `break` when you see a tuple whose first two elements match the position you're looking for.

Comment: okay what is a tuple? is that just a number? and this sorta sounds like exactly what im looking for could you maybe go into more detail?

Comment: @user2966742: Oops! I thought you were using tuples. [Tuples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) are sort of like a list, but immutable and possibly more lightweight. If you pretend I said list rather than tuple you'll probably be alright.

Comment: ahhh okay how would you set it up to look at only the first two elements?

Comment: @user2966742: Use `==` on each of the first two elements and use `and`, e.g. if you have the two lists `a` and `b`, `a[0] == b[0] and a[1] == b[1]`.